# Kafka log compaction pointers

Tags: apache-kafka

Reading about log compaction on a topic, I was wondering if there is any way for a consumer to get hold of any of the positions/offsets of the following?

- end of the head
- start of the tail
- compaction cleaner point

Basically the point at which the compacted and non-compacted parts of the log meet?

I've read that there is a `cleaner-offset-checkpoint` file that sits on the broker at `/var/lib/kafka/data/cleaner-offset-checkpoint` but is the info in this file available to a consumer?

My use case is a consumer that will consume compacted keys one way and non-compacted keys another way.

thanks for any advice.

**UPDATE:**

thinking for example of a topic holding various customer events like here https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/; new customer, customer updates name, customer updates address, etc. Log compaction, I believe, will leave one event per customer in the tail but still many events per customer in the head (assuming compaction is slower than message production..?) A new consumer of this topic would have to treat all compacted messages as CREATES, but then also treat non-compacted message as their more fine grained event? In any case I was wondering if a consumer could tell how far along a topic compaction has got, at any given time?

Comment: What specifically is your use case? Why wouldn't you want to compact everything into a table?

Comment: added reply in main post as was too long for comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, with the consumer api, no.

If you want to check that checkpoint file on disk, you could use Jssh, for example, to access a broker, and read the file. If it has offset data, you could then use seek methods, but keep in mind that the Log Cleaner thread may be actively running when you seek to or consume that data

> A new consumer of this topic would have to treat all compacted messages as CREATES, but then also treat non-compacted message as their more fine grained event?

I don't think this is a valid use case. For a stream of customer updates, you'd just update a new customer model in a table via a streaming `reduce` function. If any consumer restarts, it'll have to always read from the beginning of the topic to rebuild its local state then continue reading any updates to those stored values, so doesn't make sense to skip past them all, or have two separate consumers

I also don't necessarily think you need different models. Some UUID would be unique, and every event can contain the full model of a "customer". Most fields can remain optional/nullable until they are provided with a new message with all those fields set (or not), and this defines a batch update since you can set/update/remove multiple attributes at once. If you need more granularity, that's also possible to define at the producer level by storing and looping over your attributes and producing individual "customer" objects with each new attribute

Comment: Thanks fro that. I  think i'm having difficulty understanding this, but I think this is down to me learning stopping at Topics and not looking at Streams and (K?) tables. This is mainly down to the approach I've taken to use Apache Camel with Kafka. Maybe how things should work would be clearer with some Streams and KTable understanding...

Comment: Imagine a chess/checkers board. How would you save the board? A table shows the current state of all pieces, but storing the full board on every move wastes a lot of space. Instead, given a known starting state, storing a stream of moves can be consumed from the beginning to build the board at any state in time... Give each game board an ID, and that'll scale indefinitely, and represents Kafka topic partitioning

Comment: cheers for taking this time to explain. I'm reading up more on kafka. For completeness here is a cross post i did before your reply where one reply mentions that log compaction means having to deal with UPSERT semantics, which is what I was hoping to avoid....and hopefully can still do after more reading!... https://groups.google.com/g/debezium/c/V5yGD46hfGk

Comment: Right, I think Gunnar and I said the same thing. "an update event should contain the complete full row state"